# Styling Treeview Qt Show Number of Elements

Tags: qt

Is it possible to customize the TreeView in QT? I would liket o add the number of files (counting them myself) to the filename? Do i have to use a Proxy-Model? Sandbox Style Code-Snippets would be great.

[image]

Comment: It is. Proxy-Model is probably the best way to go. Check the docs for having proxy-model examples. Maybe having an index is a good idea to remain a fast repsonding model. Index-refresh could be done using QtConcurrent().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`QIdentityProxyModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qidentityproxymodel.html) and override `data` method. Pseudo-code:

```
int MyProxyModel::myFileCount(const QModelIndex &index)
{
  return 42; // You code here
}

QVariant MyProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role)
{
  const QVariant orig = QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, role);

  switch (role)
  {
  case Qt::DisplayRole:
    return QString("%1 (%2)").arg( orig.toString() ).arg( myFileCount( index ) );
  default:
    break;
  }

  return orig;
}

// Usage:
/* yourModel = new YourOriginalFileSystemModel(); */
QAbstractItemModel* proxy = new MyProxyModel(this);
proxy->setSource( yourModel );
view->setModel( proxy );
```

Comment: Just to make sure, are you inheriting from QAbstractItemModel and then overriding a virtual function called "data" ?

Comment: No, you should have your model. You don't need to change it. But you should make another class, that interhits `QIdentityProxyModel` (as described in my answer).

Comment: You should understand, that proxy model doesn't collect any data. When data is needed proxy model requests it from original (source) model and overrides it, if necessary.